# check if value inside array already exists

Tags: c++

Im a beginner to C++. Its my first year in college. Im completely stuck at this.I have to make a program which takes input 4 strings then check if some value already exists if it does then output value exists and thats it, if not, if they all are unique(all 4 strings) then output them in ascending order.Code bellow works and it already outputs them in ascending order, but how to find if values repeats before writing them?

sorry for my bad English guys i hope u understand what I am trying to say here

```
string name[4];
string temp;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    cout<<"Enter "<<i+1<<" string"<<endl;
    getline(cin,name[i]);
}

for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<4;j++){
        if(name[i]>name[j]){
            temp=name[i];
            name[i]=name[j];
            name[j]=temp; 
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    cout<<name[i]<< " ";
}
```

Comment: So, the user cannot input the same name twice?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `std::set`, if you're allowed to use that.

Comment: If user inputs the same name then program inputs that name which already is entered(duplicate) and program ends, if all 4 strings are unique program first arrange them in ascending order then write them.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
        if((name[i]==name[j]) && (i!=j)){
            cout<<"already exits";
        }
```

Comment: Surely equality comparison is symmetric?!

Comment: Ye man I know this, but what if this is false and all 4 strings are unique, how to skip when checking and continue to print them in ascending order.I tried with else bellow but it wont work. I mean it works but prints them in couple times instead one for each.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the string comparison to check it before pushing it. This is if you want to check that the string is unique, not if you have shared words within each string (which is slightly more complicated.

```
string name[4];
string temp;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    cout<<"Enter "<<i+1<<" string"<<endl;
    getline(cin,name[i]);
}
int failed = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {        
        // Check if the string is the same as any previous strings.
        if (name[i].compare(name[j]) != 0)
        {
             failed = 1;
             cout<<"String exists multiple times: "<<name[i];
        }
    }
}
// Check if there were any shared strings
if(failed==0)
{
   for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
   {
       cout<<name[i]<< " ";
   }
}
```

Reference:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: You can just check `name[i] == name[j]`

Comment: @AndyG True, just my personal coding style. That might be more readable though.

Answer (score 0):

So the best way is going to be to use a better container!

Lets have a look at a `std::set` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

> std::set is an associative container that contains a sorted set of
>   unique objects.

So how can we best use this, there are many examples, but we can look at your particular one.

```
#include <set> // For Set

int main() {

    set<string> names; // our fun easy ordered set.
    string name; // a name to read in
    unsigned int nameCounter = 0; // a counter

    // loop until we have 4 correct names. 
    while (nameCounter < 4) {
        cout<<"Enter "<<nameCounter+1<<" name"<<endl;
        getline(cin,name);
        // Check that when they enter it into the set that it is actually inserted.
        // Here we are being clever because "insert" returns a tuple with a bool
        // to tell us if we put it in correctly. 
        if (!names.insert(name).second) {
            cout << "That was not unique!" << endl;
        } else {
            nameCounter++;
        }
    }

    // Now we can loop through the names which is already sorted for us!
    for (auto listName : names) {
            cout << listName << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Wasn't that easy!? It is almost always better to utilize the `std` library than do things your self!

Here is a live [example](http://ideone.com/WiPSKs).

Comment: i am only allowed to use arrays, sorry for not saying it before, cant edit now.